# Displaying even numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

I need to display the even numbers in an array (in Psuedocode), and I am totally lost on how to do that.

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
Begin write_evens(in numbers As Array of Integers, in array_size As Integer)
    Declare count As Integer
    Set count ← 0
While count < size
*******I'm stuck on what to do in the loop*****
Set count ← count + 1
```

{edit}

Here's where I am:

```
Begin write_evens(in numbers As Array of Integers, in array_size As Integer)
    Declare count As Integer
    Set count ← 0
    While count < size
    If array_size % 2 == 0 
    Write array_Size
End if
    Set count ← count + 1
End
```

Comment: The pseudo-code you should write inside the loop is `if is_even(count) then print(count)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo to test if the number is even. So something like: print <- if MOD(numbers[count]) == 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode that should do as required.  Let me know if you need any clarification.

```
function write_evens(A array of integers)
    int i = 0;
    while i < A.length
        if (i%2 == 0)
           print A[i] + " "
        i++
```

Comment: I updated my original question to what I have so far.